# Truffle develop vs Ganache. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Tags: truffle, ganache

Now that Ganache is usable, I don't see a reason to use *truffle develop* anymore.

Is there still a scenario where the latter is preferred?

Comment: I think it's just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle develop uses ganache-cli under the hood, the command is there just for simplicity. Using truffle develop abstracts configuring your truffle project to connect to your ganache instance.

Chances are if you are a new developer, configuring network properties might not be what you want to spend your time on.